# Etherjs Transfer BNB Return 0 and doesnt end to Receiver Address

Tags: nodejs, ethereumjs, binance-smart-chain

Hi im new to smart contract. Im trying to code a simple transfer using etherjs and nextjs. Basically below are my code

```
import {ethers} from 'ethers';
const ContractAddr = '0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52'; /* BNB Contract address */
const ContractABI =[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"}]

const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
const signer = provider.getSigner();

let numberOfTokens = ethers.utils.parseUnits('0.2', 18)
const Contract = new ethers.Contract(ContractAddr,ContractABI,signer)
const receiver = '0x8CA65A3Ce90d31a88FAa747c695183C2aefe537f';

Contract.transfer(receiver, numberOfTokens).then((transferResult) => {
            console.log(transferResult)
            alert("sent token")
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.error('error',error);
          });
```

on my metamask, it pops up as i wanted as follow :

[image]

however when i check the transaction details at the BSCscan Testnet, its showing 0 Value an the receiver is the Contract Address instead of the receiver.

https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x3278d9668391eee98aadf83e8ae58a0b999f2e9c3e5f47a21f504e1c04b24814

Help. Been stuck for a week searching high and low for similiar issue at Stackoverflow :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your specific case:**

The BNB token contract only exists on Ethereum Mainnet: https://etherscan.io/address/0xb8c77482e45f1f44de1745f52c74426c631bdd52. On the other networks this is just an address without any contract.

On BSC and BSC testnet BNB is the native token (similar to ETH on Ethereum). Therefor if you want to transfer BNB on BSC you would perform a native coin transfer.

**Some general context:**

You have to differentiate between transfering the native coin and transfering an ERC20 token.

When you transfer the native coin (e.g. BNB on BSC) you will send a transaction where `to` is the receiver of the coin and `value` is the amount that should be sent. There will be no `data` in this case.

When you sent an ERC20 token you interact with the token contract. With this interaction you tell the token what action to perform. So the target of the transaction will be the token contract and the value will be 0 (since you are not transfering native coins). The operation that you want to perform is encoded in the `data` field.